# Broadband modem / parental control router conflict

Tags: router, firewall, adsl, fiber

We have recently moved to a new house and have full speed Fibre broadband (which is also new to us).

In our old house I used a combination of the ISP's ADSL modem and a Gryphon router; **which worked fine together - no problem.**

The Gryphon connects to the modem via Ethernet and I've given the Gryphon the same SSID as the modem (which is fine as the modem's Wifi is off).

Devices then connect to the Gryphon's wireless network.

In the new house this doesn't work very well, as **several/many times during the day the Gryphon loses it's Internet connection**; even though the ADSL modem is connected just fine.

Is this anything to do with DHCP leases I wonder; perhaps a conflict?

**The only thing that is different is that we are in a new house, with new Fibre broadband.**

What can I check? Thanks

Update #1 - I cant find a way to access the Gryphon logs.

Comment: You may need to update the Gryphon to a newer device and check for Fiber compatibility before you purchase.

Comment: Does the "Gryphon" perhaps have any logs that you can share? Are you sure it's not simply crashing?

Comment: If your 'modem' has WiFi it's likely a combo-box, modem/router. if you're using your own router directly behind it, the trick is usually to find how to switch the ISP's box to 'modem only' mode.

Comment: I've switched-off Wifi on the modem. Do I still need to use "modem only" mode? @Tetsujin

Comment: Yes. It turns it into nothing more than a 'dumb' modem & bypasses *all* router structure, letting you use your own router to cover all relevant functionality [it may also change the subnet it sits on; mine switches from 192.168.100.1 to 192.168.0.1 Look it up in your ISP's info so you don't get caught out]

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying this...https://community.plus.net/t5/My-Router/Hub-One-as-a-modem-only/m-p/1810491#M26397

Comment: If changing to passthru mode doesn't work out, you can usually have the ISP replace the modem just to be sure it's not causing problems. I also recommend checking your router for logs happening at the same time

Comment: I’d like to stress that this _absolutely must work_ irrespective of what the upstream device is, modem, router or whatever. Changes in this regard are not required. What _is_ required is diagnosing what the actual issue is. Right now, we have but an observation: internet access is down. We don’t even know how it is down. “Page not found”, timeout, Wi-Fi down, …

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @tetsujin who said "*If your 'modem' has WiFi it's likely a combo-box, modem/router. if you're using your own router directly behind it, the trick is usually to find how to switch the ISP's box to 'modem only' mode*"

I enabled "bridge mode" on the ISP's box and have not had any issues since.

The full approach was:

1. Factory reset the ISP box and the Gryphon
2. Connect ISP box and ensure the Internet connection is working
3. Connect the Gryphon to the ISP box via Ethernet
4. Start Gryphon installation steps i.e. scan the QR code.
5. On one of the screens you are asked if you want to configure PPPoE. At this point, put the ISP box into Bridge Mode.
6. On the Gryphon choose the configure PPPoE option and enter your ISP credentials.